# grep regex pair of words without special symbols between

Tags: regex, grep

get stuck with this task:

i have line, that contains word from group, some words/digest/minus text, space and once again word from group and text

for example words first or second:

```
"first-12qwe32 second-4324"

"first-123ewq first-asf-ds"

"second-123 first-45-6"
```

but not:

```
"second-123" 

"second-123 \" first-45-6" 

"second-123 \t first-45-6" 

"first-45-6-second-ffuu"
```

i try this:

```
grep -e "first-\w*\|second-\w* first-\w*\|second-\w*"

grep -e "(first-\|second-)\w* (first-\|second-)\w*
```

and same variants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -e "\w*[-a-z0-9]* \w*[-a-z0-9]*"
```

This will match all of your to-be-matched examples and not match all of your non-to-be-matched examples. You may want to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: my words list limited by known group. how can I adapt your solution?
try 
grep -e "(first\|second)+[-a-z0-9]* (first\|second)+[-a-z0-9]*"
didn't work